# How to use request.path in Django View get_context_data?

Tags: django, django-views

I want to use last part of the url in get_context_data in the view.

For example: if I have  **/foo/bar** I want to get **/bar** in a variable in the view.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx["url"] = request.path.split('/')[:-1]
    return ctx
```

Comment: use `self.request.path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the request object with `self.request`. So you here can implement this with:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['url'] = self.request.path.split('/')[:-1]
        return ctx
```

Note that by using `[:-1]` you construct a *list* of strings. So it will be `['', '/foo']` when you enter `/foo/bar`. Or `['']` for `/foo`, or `['', '/foo', '/bar']` for `/foo/bar/qux`.

You might want to use `.rsplit(..)` here:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['url'] = self.request.path.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
        return ctx
```

Comment: hey. Self.request.path worked. Thanks. But in the template I get: 
 ['', 'foo']

Comment: @gakekobetsi: you can make use of `.rsplit(..)`, see edit.